# Save just the Material part of a .blend file

Tags: node-editor, shaders, linked-data

Can you just save parts of a .blend file? And link them in later?

thanks

Comment: Hello :). Yes, you can have a .blend that only contains a material (and no geometry) if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Jachym, thanks for the reply. I was looking more to just save a Node tree from the Shader window as a stand-alone file to link in. Many times I would like to sare a node tree but not all the other data of a project. Yes, there are other ways of doing this but are awkward at best.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about :). I have a library of individual *nodegroups* that I link/append into my projects.

Comment: so how do I save just the one node "material" data out of a .blnd file? thanks